# Weird Body Overflow - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with setting an image to 100% of the body height. I am getting this odd white space at the bottom of the page, even though I have margin and padding set to 0 on everything. I could just use `overflow-y: hidden`, but I would prefer to just figure out why it's doing that. Thanks!

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1429554429301-1c7d5ae2d42e?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="background" />
```

Comment: Use vh and vw units, works like a charm.

Comment: Use `display:block`. By the way setting the `margin` and `padding` for `*` selector isn't a good practice

Comment: @Mattonit Thanks! Why is it unadvisable?

Comment: @H.Allen It is completely acceptable in the manner you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: block` on the `img`.